# Get span text from a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

The website I'm trying to scrape looks like this:

```
<div align="center" class="movietable">
    <span style="width:45px;height:47px;vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;">
        <a href="browse.php?cat=19"><img border="0" src="styles/images/cat/hd.png" alt="HdO"></a>
    </span>
</div>
<div align="left" class="movietable">
    <span style="padding:0px 5px;width:455px;height:47px;vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="" href="details.php?id=578197" data-original-title="<img src='https://trasd.tmdb.org//tqistSlQGQVlvDZHweD.jpg'>">
            <b>GET THIS TEXT</b></a><br><font class="small">[Action, Horror, Sci-Fi]</font>
        </span>
    </div>
```

How can I extract:

1. The text in the `<b>` tag - in this case `GET THIS TEXT`
2. The content of the font_class= 'small' - in this case this would be `Action, Horror, Sci-Fi`
   .movietable b works great!!
3. The img_scr link - in thiscase it would be `https://trasd.tmdb.org//tqistSlQGQVlvDZHweD.jpg`

I have no ideea how to do this

Comment: Please share your code snippet for what have you tried so far and if any exceptions you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are CSS selectors you can use:

1. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[align=left] b')`
2. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[align=left] .small')`
3. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title]').get_attribute('data-original-title')`

Comment: Thank you Lukasz! Any hints for no 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can access all of them using xpath:

```
1) [parents before this div]/div[2]/span/a/b 

2) [parents before this div]/div[2]/span/font

3) [parents before this div]/div[1]/span/a/img

[parents before this div] should be /html/body/...
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the items you can use the following solution:

- *GET THIS TEXT*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='movietable' and @align='left']/span/a[@data-toggle='tooltip' and @data-placement='bottom']/b").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- *[Action, Horror, Sci-Fi]*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='movietable' and @align='left']/span//font[@class='small']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- *https://trasd.tmdb.org//tqistSlQGQVlvDZHweD.jpg*:

  ```
  img_src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='movietable' and @align='left']/span/a[@data-toggle='tooltip' and @data-placement='bottom']").get_attribute("data-original-title")
  src = img_src.replace("'", "-").split("-")
  print(src[1])
  ```